# Rss feed does not returns all the rows which is come from database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been generating custom rss feed in my word press when i am retrieving the data from database it show the counts correct but when i am return as rss feed it not returning the data correctly

Here is my code

```
 $connection = @mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
        or die('Could not connect to database');
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME)
        or die ('Could not select database');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM bm_posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'news' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY ID DESC ";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Could not execute query");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title=$row['post_title']; 
    $link=$row['guid']; 
    $description=$row['post_content'];   
   $descriptLimit = substr($description, 0, 50);
   $text=htmlspecialchars($descriptLimit, ENT_COMPAT,'ISO-8859-1', true);

  $date=$row['post_date'];

        echo "<item>";
        echo "<title>$title</title>"; 
        echo "<link>$link</link>"; 
        echo "<description>$text</description>"; 
        echo "<pubDate>$date</pubDate>";
        echo "</item>"; 

    } 
 echo "</channel></rss>";
```

Comment: It is rather impossible that this would not output one item for each single row that is in the result set. How did you _check_ this? Did you look at the actual XML code of the RSS feed - or did you let yourself get fooled by what some RSS reader tool displayed perhaps …?

Comment: i am getting like this https://beavismorgan.com/customfeed.php

Comment: `echo "<description>$trimchar</description>";` - you don’t have a variable named `$trimchar` anywhere else in that code you have shown. Did you mean `$text` here?

Comment: yes i mean text i forgot to change and post

Comment: _“i am getting like this”_ - and, what is _wrong_ with that? That seems to contain 1149 `item` elements right now, so how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: i wanna list all the 1149

Comment: As I just said, there appear to be exactly 1149 items in that RSS feed you have shown. So, _still_ unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have to display the 1149 records as rss feed but when i return as rss feed in my mozilla it displys 13 records i don't know why it wasn't display other records

Comment: Well then that’s because the browser has decided to only _show_ you those 13 first items - which is reasonable, because RSS actually is a format meant to _incrementally_ deliver new data. There is _nothing_ wrong with the feed itself here. Use a different program that lists _all_ the content of a feed, no matter how many items it might contain, if that’s what you need.

Comment: (Or try and actually _subscribe_ to the feed in Mozilla/Firefox, and see what happens then - because what you are looking at right now is only meant to be a _preview_ in the first place.)

Comment: Ya i will try but i have and doubt is my code is correct to feed rss

Comment: _“doubt is my code is correct to feed rss”_ - well then use the tools that are available to check it … http://www.feedvalidator.org/, https://validator.w3.org/feed/, …